# jQuery replace/remove attribute without id or tag

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am new to jquery, and I'm having trouble doing what I thought should be a very simple find and replace operation.

I want to remove disabled attribute. I already searching jquery remove sample, but always using id or tag.

```
    <td><a href="xx.html" disabled onclick="preparexForm(this,'xx')" class="btn">ok</a> </td>
```

I try this code but not working.

```
$("body *").replaceText( /disabled|disable/gi, "enable" );
```

Comment: Are you trying to remove the disabled attribute or disable text?

Comment: Like @tabz100 said, you have conflicting code. The first one is to *remove* the disabled code, and the second is to *replace* it (with "enabled"). What are you trying to do?

Comment: Also, there is [no HTML `enabled` attribute](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7708184/why-attribute-disabled-but-not-enabled).

Comment: i want to try remove

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a selector on the attribute and remove it when found. It is by the way NEVER a good idea to try to use regex/replace on HTML tags

```
$("a[disabled]").each(function() {
  $(this).removeAttr("disabled");
});
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer.